# How to Revert Vue-Drag-Resize drag event

Tags: javascript, vue.js, drag-and-drop, vue-component

After dragging an element using the [vue-drag-resize](https://github.com/kirillmurashov/vue-drag-resize) component, I need to check the coordinates where the element was dragged to and if it's not a valid location, revert the coordinates back to where the drag was started.

[Here's the sample code](https://codesandbox.io/s/j42l57jq05)

Here I assign the original value when the element is initially clicked to start the move.

```
onActivated(index) {
  this.currentFieldIndex = index;
  this.currentField.left = this.fields[this.currentFieldIndex].left;
  this.currentField.top = this.fields[this.currentFieldIndex].top;
}
```

And then when they stop the drag outside of the boundaries, I try to reassign the original coordinates back into the field like this:

```
onDragStop(rect) {
  if (rect.left < 0 || rect.top < 0) {
    this.fields[this.currentFieldIndex].left = this.currentField.left;
    this.fields[this.currentFieldIndex].top = this.currentField.top;
  } else {
    this.fields[this.currentFieldIndex].left = rect.left;
    this.fields[this.currentFieldIndex].top = rect.top;
    this.currentField.x = rect.left;
    this.currentField.y = rect.top;
  }
}
```

Interestingly enough, if I just hard-code the reset coordinates like this (below) it works fine:

```
onDragStop(rect) {
  if (rect.left < 0 || rect.top < 0) {
    this.fields[this.currentFieldIndex].left = 0; //this.currentField.left;
    this.fields[this.currentFieldIndex].top = 0; //this.currentField.top;
  } else {
    this.fields[this.currentFieldIndex].left = rect.left;
    this.fields[this.currentFieldIndex].top = rect.top;
    this.currentField.x = rect.left;
    this.currentField.y = rect.top;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that since you never update your field to the new location when it fails, you are just setting the same value as it previously had. (You start moving from `left: 100, top: 100`. then because you only update `fields`on "drag stop", you then tell fields to be updated with the coordinates you got `onActivated`(still 100, 100).)

Vue will not register any changes if the value is `===` the old value. This results in your rectangle not moving back to start, yet again because Vue doesn't think anything is new.

There are multiple ways to solve this.

**Solution 1:** You can, for example, add a decimal to your new value;

```
onDragStop(rect) {
  if (rect.left < 0 || rect.top < 0) {
    alert("revert!!");
    this.fields[this.currentFieldIndex].left = this.currentField.left + 0.1; //<--
    this.fields[this.currentFieldIndex].top = this.currentField.top + 0.1; //<--
  } else {
    //...
  }
}
```

This, of course, makes your rectangle off by `n`.

**Solution 2:** You can continuously update `this.fields[x]` via the [dragging event](https://github.com/kirillmurashov/vue-drag-resize#dragging);

```
onDragging(rect) {
  this.fields[this.currentFieldIndex].left = rect.left;
  this.fields[this.currentFieldIndex].top = rect.top;
}
```

This is a more resource heavy solution, but you will always have the correct values at all times.

Comment: Thank you!  Give me a day to test this out and I'll reward you the bounty.